# Bootstrap4 customized breadcrumbs in angular

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

Has anyone implemented customized bread crumbs based on click of a chart and its title adds to bread crumb array and display on top. Similarly a hierarchy of clicked pie chart titles are displayed  as bread crumbs. These bread crumbs acts as back functionality too.  I have started working on that, but somehow I am not liking it. I want to discuss how it is done so I can start working on it and post that code so we can go over it.